# error: no matching function for call to 'EVP_EncryptInit_ex'

Tags: c++, openssl, blockchain, litecoin

I tried to compile `litecoind` for litecoin, but an error occurred.

The source code was taken from the latest version of litecoin.

Here is part of the code:

```cpp
bool CCrypter::Decrypt(const std::vector<unsigned char>& vchCiphertext, CKeyingMaterial& vchPlaintext)
{
    if (!fKeySet)
        return false;

    // plaintext will always be equal to or lesser than length of ciphertext
    int nLen = vchCiphertext.size();
    int nPLen = nLen, nFLen = 0;

    vchPlaintext = CKeyingMaterial(nPLen);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

    bool fOk = true;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
    if (fOk) fOk = EVP_DecryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, chKey, chIV);
    if (fOk) fOk = EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, &vchPlaintext[0], &nPLen, &vchCiphertext[0], nLen);
    if (fOk) fOk = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&ctx, (&vchPlaintext[0])+nPLen, &nFLen);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);


    if (!fOk) return false;

    vchPlaintext.resize(nPLen + nFLen);
    return true;
}
```

I searched for an answer, but did not find a suitable one for me.

As I understand it, this is related to the version of openssl.

There was a mistake before

> error: field 'ctx' has incomplete type EVP_CIPHER_CTX.

Since I'm on a new openssl, I replaced it with `EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();` and the error disappeared but a new one appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ctx` is an `EVP_CIPHER_CTX*` pointer, which is what the [`EVP_Decrypt...()` functions](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_DecryptInit_ex.html) take, then you need to drop the [`&` address-of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) when passing `ctx` to them, eg:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, ...);
EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, ...);
EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, ...);

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```